# Is there a way to Lock Flutter App during user inactivity after specified duration

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working on an App,

where if the app is inactive [is not being used, or noactivity] for a certain period of duration, the lock screen is expected to show [ asking for PIN in order to continue using the app].

**Package I've tried:**

--.**flutter_app_lock** [Flutter Lock app](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_lock)

usage [according to documentation]:

- can lock screen when app open
- can lock app when app run in background / minimized
- can lock app when manually asked to lock app [calling some Applock.of(context).lock enable() function]

I can't seem to get it to work for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with using a GestureDetector as suggested, but it didn't work as expected. The problem was that I received a continuous stream of gestures when there was no activity. This includes when I tried the more restrictive onTap: callback.

I saw this in debug mode on an emulator. I didn't experiment further to see if real phones manifest the same behavior, because even if they don't know, they might in the future: There's clearly no spec guarantee that a GestureDetector won't receive spurious events. For something security-related like an inactivity timeout, that's not acceptable.

In my use case, I decided that it was OK to instead detect when the application is invisible for more than a set amount of time. My reasoning for my expected usage is that the real danger is when the app is invisible, and they forget it's there.

Setting this kind of inactivity timeout is pretty easy. I arrange to call `startKeepAlive()` at the moment the app gains access to sensitive information (e.g. after a password is entered). For my usage, just crashing out of the app after the timeout is fine; obviously one could get more sophisticated if needed. Anyhoo, here's the relevant code:

```
Timer _keepAliveTimer;

void _keepAlive(bool visible) {
  _keepAliveTimer?.cancel();
  if (visible) {
    _keepAliveTimer = null;
  } else {
    _keepAliveTimer = Timer(_inactivityTimeout, () => exit(0));
  }
}

class _KeepAliveObserver extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch(state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        _keepAlive(true);
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        _keepAlive(false);  // Conservatively set a timer on all three
        break;
    }
  }
}

/// Must be called only when app is visible, and exactly once
void startKeepAlive() {
  assert(_keepAliveTimer == null);
  _keepAlive(true);
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(_KeepAliveObserver());
}
```